# Unhandled exception calling a .exe file on pocket pc emulator application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, pocketpc, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to run this code on vc2005 on pocket PC emulator but it gives me a win32unhandled exception

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  Proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"WM_flowm.exe";
  Proc.Start();
}
```

The WM_flowm.exe is the flite tts which can run on windows mobile without problems, but I need to call it in my C# code.

the call stack

```
System.dll!System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = {System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo}) + 0xcb bytes   

System.dll!System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() + 0x3f bytes
```

stopped here ===

> try_DLL.exe!try_DLL.Form1.button1_Click(object sender = {Text = "button1"}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 29 + 0x6 bytes    C#

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) + 0x15 bytes 

System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) + 0x32 bytes  

System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(Microsoft.AGL.Forms.WM wm = WM_BUTTON_NOTIFYCLICKED, int wParam = 0, int lParam = 0) + 0x17 bytes   

System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(Microsoft.AGL.Forms.WM wm = WM_BUTTON_NOTIFYCLICKED, int wParam = 0, int lParam = 0) + 0x9 bytes  

System.Windows.Forms.dll!Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(System.IntPtr hwnMain = 1114117) 

System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form fm = {try_DLL.Form1}) + 0x1a bytes  

try_DLL.exe!try_DLL.Program.Main() Line 15 + 0xa bytes  C#
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information on the exception you received before we can help you.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: i added the call stack and there is no more info , just to know that the .exe file only work on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path of the file. If the file is in \Progam Files\WM_Flowm\:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    Proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"\Program Files\WM_flowm\WM_flowm.exe";
    Proc.Start();
}
```